# Kubernetes spring boot service does work inside the cluster but get's white label 404 error outside

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have this spring boot app container in a pod and a service mapped to access the app, inside a minikube cluster. when I use an exec command and try to access API endpoints it does work fine. But after I exposed it using an Nginx ingress controller it shows Whitelabel 404 error for every request.
I did add the ingress minikube addon and configured the ingress controller using a yaml file.
here's the ingress.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /path/.*
          backend:
            serviceName: spring-app
            servicePort: 8080
```

Any tips on how to solve this?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Add pod deployment yaml

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /path/(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: spring-app
            servicePort: 8080
```

For more information, please check [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/).

Comment: Sure lemme try!